# Parser Error when running Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a Asp.net web application. When I run the web forms using IIS Express the following error is displayed.

[image]

I've had a look at the file that is causing the error but the line that is apparently the cause of the error isn't even in this file.
This is the file that is causing the error.

[image]

Comment: @user9938, I resolved the issue by cleaning and rebuilding the project. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace used in the Global.cs file [screenshot is not from top of the global.cs file. Usually this occurs when namespaces changed.

Comment: I've had a look at the file, namespace hasn't changed. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The Global.aspx and Global.aspx.cs files are interconnected hence you are getting the error shown in the Global.aspx file instead of Global.aspx.cs

Comment: Hi, Turns out all I had to was clean and rebuild the project. Thank you for the help.